# Pythonスクリプトから型ヒントを除去する

Tags: python, python3

Pythonスクリプトから型ヒントを自動で**除去**する方法はありますか．

- 除去前（例）

```py
def hoge() -> None:
    print('Hello World')

fuga: str | None = 'Guido'
piyo: list[int] = [1, 9, 9, 1]
```

- 除去後（例）

```py
def hoge():
    print('Hello World')

fuga = 'Guido'
piyo = [1, 9, 9, 1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733877/remove-type-hints-in-python-source-programmatically

Comment: 「自動で除去」とは何かツールを使用することを意図していますか？

Comment: はい．必ずしも純粋なPythonモジュールによって除去される必要はありません．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LibCST](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)を使ってType Hintsの開始行桁、終了行桁を取得することができました。
対象ファイルから`Type Hints`以外を出力するコード例です。

**コード例**　※修正版
同一行に複数の`Type Hints`があるとき、２つ目以降の`Type Hints`が除去されないバグに対応しました。主な修正点は以下です。

- 修正した行を対象としてさらに`Type Hints`を削除する。
- `Type Hints`を削除すると桁位置が変わるので、Type Hintsの開始行桁、終了行桁を逆順に処理する。

```
from typing import Optional
import libcst as cst
from libcst.metadata import WhitespaceInclusivePositionProvider


class Printer(cst.CSTVisitor):  # Type Hintsの開始行桁、終了行桁を取得するVisitor
    METADATA_DEPENDENCIES = (cst.metadata.PositionProvider, WhitespaceInclusivePositionProvider)
    pos_annotations: list[(int, int, int, int)] = []    # Type Hintsの開始行、開始行桁、終了行、終了桁のリスト

    def __init__(self, pos_annotations: list[(int, int, int, int)]):
        self.pos_annotations = pos_annotations

    def visit_Annotation(self, node: "Annotation") -> Optional[bool]:
        pos_start = self.get_metadata(cst.metadata.WhitespaceInclusivePositionProvider, node).start
        pos_end = self.get_metadata(cst.metadata.WhitespaceInclusivePositionProvider, node).end
        self.pos_annotations.append((pos_start.line, pos_start.column, pos_end.line, pos_end.column))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = "対象ファイル.py"
    tree = cst.parse_module(open(file_path, encoding="utf-8").read())   # 対象ファイルのCSTツリー
    wrapper = cst.metadata.MetadataWrapper(tree)
    pos_annotations: list[(int, int, int, int)] = []    # Type Hintsの開始行、開始行桁、終了行、終了桁のリスト
    result = wrapper.visit(Printer(pos_annotations))

    def print_no_annotation(pos_annotations: list[(int, int, int, int)], line_no: int, line: int):
        skip = False
        print_line = line + "\n"
        for item in reversed(pos_annotations):
            pos_start_line, pos_start_column, pos_end_line, pos_end_column = item
            if pos_start_line < line_no < pos_end_line:
                skip = True
                break
            elif pos_start_line == line_no == pos_end_line:
                print_line = print_line[0:pos_start_column] + print_line[pos_end_column:]
                continue
            elif pos_start_line == line_no:
                print_line = print_line[0:pos_start_column]
                continue
            elif pos_end_line == line_no:
                print_line = print_line[pos_end_column:]
                continue
        if skip:
            return
        print(print_line, end='')


    line_no = 1
    for line in tree.code.splitlines():
        print_no_annotation(pos_annotations, line_no, line)
        line_no += 1
```

**バージョン**
Python 3.10.5

**LibCSTのインストール**
pip install libcst

---

当初はPythonの組み込みastモジュールを使用しようと考えたのですが、空白やコメントの情報が失われるようなので断念しました。※動作確認したわけではありません。
LibCSTは空白やコメントもノードとして保持されることがわかり、`Type Hints`のノードを削除する方法を試したのですが、変数の`Type Hints`の除去で発生する例外をどうしても解消することができませんでした。※関数の復帰値の`Type Hints`の除去はうまくいきました。

LibCSTを使うのであればこの方法が本来の方法だと思いますが残念です。

今回の回答は少し強引ですが`Type Hints`の開始行桁、終了行桁を求め、それ以外を出力する方法です。

Comment: ありがとうございます．大方期待通りに動作します．ただ同一行にアノテーションが複数個存在する場合（例：def foo(hoge: str, fuga: int): ...）（質問のコード例に記載せず申し訳ありません）2つ目以降のアノテーションは無視されるため，アノテーションが完全に除去されるまで再帰的に運用する必要があります．

Comment: @dike 同一行に複数のタイプヒントがあるケースの考慮不足ですね。ちょっと考えてみます。

Comment: @dike もぐら叩き的で恐縮ですが、指摘いただいたケースには対応しました。よろしければご確認ください。※「Type Hintsのノードを削除」または「Type Hints以外のノードでツリーを再構築」が本流だと思いますがすぐには実現できないのが残念です。